# How to fix "the server response was 5.5.1 authentication required" problem stated by SMTP server?

Tags: vb.net

The code cannot run successfully and display the issue "The server response was 5.5.1 authentication required" even if there is no bugs for the program and I have turned on the "Access for less secure apps". What should I do?

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class Form1

Private mail As New MailMessage

Private smtp As New SmtpClient

Private Sub createmsg()
    mail.From = New MailAddress(frrm.Text.Trim)
    mail.To.Add(tosb.Text.Trim)
    mail.Subject = subj.Text
    mail.Body = body.Text
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
    mail.IsBodyHtml = False
End Sub

Private Sub createsmtp()
    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(frrm.Text.Trim, pass.Text.Trim)
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
End Sub
Private Sub sendmsg()

    smtp.Send(mail)

End Sub

Private Sub send_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles send.Click
    Try
        createmsg()
        createsmtp()
        sendmsg()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
End class
```

Comment: Move `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False` before setting the new credentials (otherwise you'll simply remove any credential). After that, verify whether you have set `Less secure app access` to  `On` in your account's configuration. Does `frrm.Text` reference a Google account?

Comment: It means that `mail.From`, the Account that sends the Mail message, is specified in `frrm.Text`. You didn't answer my question, though.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you really helped me out. Now my code is able to run!!!